# How to exit from GRUB

Tags: grubrescue

I press the shift key to enter GRUB while booting and I changed my password.
How can I exit GRUB to continue booting?

Comment: I have change my password and I keep getting invalid password using GRUB root and still get invalid password please try again

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? Which password did you change? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))